# Can I remove a site's entry in the browsers history by clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I am working on a website for a women's shelter and would like to include a link to leave the site and remove its entries in the browsers history. The objective is to cover the tracks of a person seeking help.

Ideally I would like to implement this feature using something like jQuery. Currently the alternative is a page with instructions on how to manually clear the history for each browser.

Comment: Perhaps instead of clearing the history, you could flood it with garbage.

Comment: even for radiation shelter - impossible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible because of code access security concerns.  Imagine if you visited a website that cleared *your* history without your knowledge or approval.

I would probably include a prominent notice on a privacy page with some information on how to delete history, cookies, cache, etc. for some of the major browsers, as well as some info on using each major browser's privacy/incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your alternative is the only solution, and also the best one. My mind is unfortunatly not diabolical enough to think up how such an ability could be abused, but rest assured it would be.

On the other hand, explaining to users how to cover their tracks themselves will help them do so on *all* websites, not just yours.

Teach a man (or woman) to fish...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible using Javascript. You could have the content load in an iframe on another domain to protect these folks from the history entry, but it isn't the same and they would have to know the alternative domain.